# jQuery load file from different directory

Tags: jquery

I have following project structure

```
  -root
     -app.html
     -scripts/
         -jquery/
         locales.js
     -_locales/
         -en/
            -messages.json
```

in `app.html` I include the `locales.js` file in which I want to load the `messages.json` file like this

```
jQUery.get("../_locales/en/messages.json", function(data){
    alert(data);
});
```

But this does not work. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you able to access the file by putting the full url in the browser?

Comment: -1 for misleading title. I thought this is load() and so did google :'( Lucky you, I don't got rep for down voting, but just wait that day :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using .get, what you need to provide is the URL to access _locals/en/messages.json either as an absolute URL or a URL relative to the page that the javascript is running from.  To double check that your URL is working, try putting it into your location bar and making sure you get the file you expect.  So as your URL stands now, it would be `<currentPageURL>../_locales/en/messages.json`.  If that works, you will want to start debugging what's going on in your .get.  First, though, make sure your URL is valid.

Comment: I get a 404 file not found, It seems that he wants the full path, is there a way to do it with the relative path? - it works if I remove the "../", thanks!

Comment: How are you currently serving the files? Are you running a development server?

Comment: @ArtWorkAD - how about /_locales/en/messages.json (no preceeding ../)?  A path relative to server root should work.

Comment: It works now thanks, running it on localhost, just removed the "../"